# Bluetooth socket takes longer to connect

Tags: c#, android, sockets, bluetooth, xamarin.android

with my limited knowlegde about sockets I put together this code for xamarin.android:

```
    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        while (true)
        {

            socket = pairedBTDevice.CreateRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID.FromString(uuid));
            socket.ConnectAsync();
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            if (socket.IsConnected)
            {
                activity.ShowToast("Bluetooth connected");
                await OnDataReceived();
            }
            socket.Close();
        }

    });
```

it works as intended most of the time. But sometimes after I restart the socket needs about 9 seconds to connect. This happens when i close the app and open it immediately after. Has anyone some inside on why this is happening?

Comment: When you close the App, do you shutdown your socket connection also?

Comment: yes I close the streamreader and the socket in my OnDestroy() methode in my MainActivity class.